# Null Object reference with getPageTitle()

Tags: android, fragment, adapter, pager

I need to use getPageTitle in my FragmentPagerAdapter to correctly include sliding tabs, but I've currently some problems doing it.

This is my code:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private FragmentActivity activity;
//private Context context;

public static final int[] TITLES = { R.string.popularsongs, R.string.lastalbums };

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new ArtistPopularFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new ArtistAlbumsFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 2;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
{
    /*
    String s = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_titles_artist);
    CharSequence cs = s;
    return cs; */
    return activity.getResources().getText(TITLES[position]);
}

}
```

Using this code makes the app crash. How can I fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: post your layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the parameter in the constructor assign the reference to itself. Change

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

to

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, FragmentActivity activity) {
    super(fm);
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

or you could also just pass the `FragmentActivity`

```
  public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        this.activity = activity;
  }
```

and then instantiate it like `TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this)` or `new TabsPagerAdapter(this)`, depending on the one you choose

Comment: When I compile, I get "actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: I already corrected the Activity to FragmentActivity, but the other issue still remains

Comment: you have also to change your `new TabsPagerAdapter` to get the fragment activity as parameter . `new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this)` for instance